# Google Sheets: Combine duplicate rows into single row keeping separate columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Left side is data, right side is expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9vcG.png)

How do I combine duplicate rows into one while keeping separate columns?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is with `query()`, like this:

`=query( A3:H, "select A, max(B), max(C), max(D), max(E), max(F), max(G), max(H) where A is not null group by A", 0 )`

Answer (score 0):

use flatten function with query like this
=UNIQUE({QUERY( FLATTEN(a1:H),"Select * Where Col1 is not null ")})
if you don't want unique just remove unique from this